# Full breadcrumb in product listing page

Tags: magento-1.9, category, breadcrumbs

As i browse through categories and subcategories
[image]

i can see the full breadcrumb. `[Home > Electronics > Smartphone]`

But as i enter the product listing page (After i selected apple)

[image]

i can't see that full breadcrumb. It only shows parent categories. `[Home > Electronics]`

**Problem** : how to get full categories and subcategories breadcrumb in my case `[Home > Electronics > Smartphone > Apple]`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your product only belongs to one category. You could override the `getBreadcrumbPath` function in `Mage_Catalog_Helper_Data` in this way:

```
if (!$this->_categoryPath) {

   $path = array();
   $category = $this->getCategory();

   if(!$category && $this->getProduct()) {

      $categoryIds = $this->getProduct()->getCategoryIds();
      if (is_array($categoryIds) and count($categoryIds)) 
          $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(array_pop($categoryIds));
   }

   if ($category) {
   ...
```

Untested, but it should work

Comment: `Assuming your product only belongs to one category.` what is suppose to means ? if any products in the list belongs to more than one category i don't get full breadcrumb. is that ?

Comment: You would still get the full breadcrumb, but this script arbitrarily picks the last category ID assigned to the product.

Comment: Replaced, but still shows the same breadcrumb :(

Comment: @K.C. Past that point, I would need to have a nosy to be able to help you. Are you sure you overrode the helper properly? Add an `exit` in there to make sure it goes through it.